# What's common starting point to designing an icon set

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, icon

I have seen a growing number of nice icon sets throughout the years. They have fine tuned their icon sets to make it pixel perfect, well-ratio. I wonder if I want to start design my own icon set, for example a line icon set. Is there any starting point that I should start with? Like any specific grids, rule of thumbs from your experience ?

What tool will you use? 
Thanks

Comment: This is simply too broad of a question and mostly opinion. There's no one answer to this. For me, I start with a need for a particular icon and build from there. As for tools, that's really more of a personal preference. Also, don't put too much weight on grids. They can be useful, but can also just get in the way.

Comment: It depends to the target also: are you planning to design icons for a specific application or platform? Flat or 3D or *artistic* looking? To be released as Open Source or not? See for example [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html), [here](http://tango.freedesktop.org/), [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openiconlibrary/), [here](https://thenounproject.com/), [here](http://design.tutsplus.com/articles/7-principles-of-effective-icon-design--psd-147), [here](http://turbomilk.com/blog/cookbook/icon_design/10_mistakes_in_icon_design/), ...

Comment: ... the beginning :)

Answer (score 1):

Before approaching icon design, there are some guidelines and principles that are worth studying. If you want to create effective icon designs, then you should take a holistic approach to issues such as audience, size, simplicity, lighting, perspective, and style. This article gives you a good starting place for creating icons that work well together and fit seamlessly within your designs.

**1. Approach Icon Design Holistically**

**2. Consider Your Audience**

**3. Design for the Size the Icon will be Used At**

**4. Keep Icons Simple and Iconic**

**5. Cast Consistent Lighting, Reflections, and Shadows**

**6. Utilize a Limited Perspective**

**7. Create Consistent Icon Set Styles**